# Is it a pre-requisite for something to have constant mass to be a 'system' in Mechanics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, definition

I deal sometimes with control volumes, and we have closed systems, in Newtonian mechanics we often just describe a 'system' without defining if it's closed or open, if we have a 'mass flow' such as a rocket (Rocket equation) can we treat the rocket as a system, only the rocket and fuel, conserving mass, do 'Mechanical' systems need to be what we'd call a 'closed system'?

Comment: You can treat the rocket as an open system which, by definition, is one that can exchange mass with its surroundings

Comment: So the reason we need to you the rocket equation is because $f=ma$ is not usable for an 'open system', we need to account for mass flow, but is a system nonetheless?

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you are trying to solve. I was only commenting on the definition of a system, from the thermodynamics perspective. A system is closed if it does not exchange mass with its surroundings,  but can exchange energy in the form of work or heat. A system is open if it can exchange mass, as in the case of the rocket. A system is isolated if it can exchange neither mass nor energy with its surroundings.

Comment: Basically just started working with mass-flow problems such as rocket equation where newton's second law does not apply for an object of mass $m$ because it is an open system whose mass changes.